# Is there a way to find Wordpress Plugin updates without admin panel access

Tags: wordpress

I've been asked by a prospective client, to do an audit on their WordPress site.

They have asked me,
**if I can check their all plugins are up to date too but they wont / cant (yet) give me access to the admin panel**.

Is there a way I can do this?  I know I can find the WP version in the code of the site (and this one needs updating)

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: same with plugins. go to `wp-content/plugins/` folder and open one by one all plugin folders, find their details in the main file of plugin( usually the main file has same name as plugin folder )

Comment: Wtf. They can't give you access to the admin : OK, why not. But they have access to it so they should have some notification in the admin plugins page that say that plugins must be updated... they could find it.

Comment: I wouldn't be working for a client like this.

Comment: Now way to check all plugin from outside. It's too funny. you should talk to the client about this...

Comment: According to the client "you can get the information we want to see without the access" - I suspect they've given the challenge to multiple developers to weed out those who aren't up to the job

They **will** give the access at a later stage and to do the work

I have some minor misgivings with this client already this I thought should be possible reasonably easily without FTP or Admin Panel access

Answer (score 0):

You could ask them for a screenshot of their plugins page (www.example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php), and then cross-reference the versions listed there with WordPress.org to check if they are up-to-date.